# Firebase web realtime database stiring user id as undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a create user and login authentication setup with firebase realtime database. I have a `user` field in my database where I will store user data. However, I would like to create a child element under the `user` field that is the user id then the user information can be displayed under that child.
So far I have tried to create such a field with this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, set, ref, update } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-database.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signOut} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth.js";

//Signup section
signup.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    var username = document.getElementById('signup-user').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
    var schoolID = document.getElementById('signup-id').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('signup-pwd').value;
    
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password, schoolID)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user;

                update(ref(database, "user/" +user.id),{
                    username: username,
                    schoolID: schoolID,
                    email: email
                })
                alert('User Created!');
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                
                alert('Error please try again');
                // ..
            });
    });
```

But it only gives me an undefined field in my realtime database:

[image: firebase error]

Not only that but it overwrites the previous entry every time a make an new user.

Comment: Note that `update` returns a promise that indicates whether or not the database write was successful.  You're not checking that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userCredential.user` is a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#user_interface) type object, which is a subclass of [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo.md#userinfo_interface).  As you can see from the linked API documentation, User doesn't have an property called `id`.  It will always be undefined.

What you want instead is [uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo.md#userinfouid).

```
update(ref(database, "user/" + user.uid), {...})
```

Comment: Thank you can't believe that one thing is what caused all my problems